# Java JodaTime get the current DateTime

Tags: android

I am the using the Joda library to get the current DateTime in Java. Now I use

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
```

to get the current date time object. Now how can I obtain the current time of the day in non military format?

Comment: have you ever used API docs? ... do you wana convert DataTime **to-String(...)** ?

Answer (score 2):

Right from the Java docs: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html

What you're looking to do seems to be the first example there:

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
 String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

If it's not the exact format that you're looking for, Java docs will show you the way.